# Interact with Google Actions through Google Assistant SDK

Tags: google-api, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-voice

I'm working on my own voice assistant based on the Google Assistant SDK. Now I'm wondering if it's possible to also communicate with custom Google Actions. (such as games and other actions that are not built-in to the SDK itself)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when using the Assistant SDK, you have access to a fully functioning Assistant - including Actions.